# mainWindow.loadFile(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)- not working even after using 'backtick'

Tags: javascript, electron

I tried to load HTML file by using the following code 
     "mainWindow.loadFile(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)"

However, whatever I did, it did not work, and only 'index.html' worked. I really did everything. Install, reinstall. It was working fine before.

This time, I follow the instruction of the official website as follows, and suddenly that way of loading file not working.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
$ cd electron-quick-start
$ npm install && npm start
```

And below is the main.js. Why do I only have to use the old way to load a file suddenly? lol.

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  mainWindow.loadFile(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
  mainWindow.on("closed", function() {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
app.on("window-all-closed", function() {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", function() {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that you have a typo! Use file instead flie?

Comment: lol sorry. That type is not from me : ) 

One of the guys suggested changing the style of posting so that it can fit. 

Original posting was "file" : )

So, in otherwords, probably no typo.

Comment: @EdgarSugarDoughnutJin you may want to fix the typos in your question and title then. Cheers

Comment: Done. Thank you : ) bjbk

Answer (score 0):

LOL just found the reason.

When I quick installed the elctectron, basically it was

```
 mainWindow.loadFile(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
```

, and I was supposed to use "loadURL"